# Prometheus - drop labels only for specific metric

Tags: prometheus

I have the following config:

```
- job_name: node
  ec2_sd_configs:
    - region: eu-west-1

  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Name, __meta_ec2_instance_id]
      # Blackmagic to extract the Name tag or fallback to the instance_id if it doesn't exist
      regex: "^;?([^;]+).*"
      replacement: "$1"
      target_label: instance
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_aws_autoscaling_groupName]
      target_label: instance_asg
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_instance_type]
      target_label: instance_type
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_instance_state]
      target_label: instance_state
```

With this config, all metrics have the labels `instance`, `instance_asg`, `instance_type` and `instance_state`.

Now, I would like to drop `instance_type` and `instance_state` only if the metric is `foo`. In all other cases, I would like to keep the existing labels.

I read I should use `metric_relabel_config` but I don't understand how.

How can I do this?